# Ganglia fails communicate between meta and monitored nodes

Tags: linux, monitoring, monitor, multiple-monitors, ganglia

We've been advised to try Ganglia as a monitoring tool for our cluster.

The installation was pretty smooth but I have a problem with connectivity between gmond and gmetad.
Meta node is able to see(on web) only local gmond host (itself).

The configuration of gmetad (10.45.11.26 is gmetad localhost):

```
data_source "hbase" 10.45.11.26
```

The configuration of gmond(10.45.11.27 is gmond localhost):

```
cluster {
name = "hbase"
owner = "unspecified"
latlong = "unspecified"
url = "unspecified"
}

udp_send_channel {
host=10.45.11.26
port = 8649
ttl = 1
}

udp_recv_channel {
port = 8649
bind = 10.45.11.27
}

tcp_accept_channel {
port = 8649
}
```

Telnet from gmetad to gmond on port 8649 returns xml.
I can see udp traffic coming from gmond on gmetad node (tcpdump)

What I'm missing here?

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if you still need help, but it can help to add

```
globals {
  (......)
  send_metadata_interval = 60 /*gmond heartbeats in secs */
 }
```

in gmond.conf

In this case, you may have to wait 60 seconds after node startup before it is seen.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I already solved the problem. it was matter of incorrect settings for data_source,trusted_hosts configuration in gmetad.conf